# Find all values of $k$ such that the system has no solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following linear system:

$x_1-4x_2+4x_3=4$
$4x_2-2x_3=k$
$-x_1+8x_2-6x_3=-1$

This is what I did so far in attempt to solve it (I highly doubt I did it correctly)
[image: my attempt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work seems ok but you did more than necessary if the only objective is to determine for which values of $k$ the system has no solution. You end up with $0=3-k$ and this implies that $k$ has to be 3, otherwise you have a contradiction.

If you look at your system, you can see this faster. In your original system of equations (I'll name them (1), (2) and (3) from top to bottom), the left hand sides of the three equations satisfy the relation
$$(2)-(1)=(3)$$
In order for the system to have a solution, the right hand sides have to satisfy the same relation, meaning:
$$k-4= -1 \Leftrightarrow k = \ldots$$
For all other values of $k$, the system can't have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are no solutions if this set is contradictory. Adding the first and the last (to eliminate the $x_1$ term because eq. 2 doesn't have it) gives $4x_2-2x_3=3$. This makes our life much easier, as this is the same LHS as eq. 2. Thus Ang value of $κ$ other than $3$ forms a contradiction.